# Forwarding variable arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, remoting

I'm encapsulating a call to a remoting service in my own RemoteObject class. This all works fine except when I have to deal with variable parameters that are being passed to the remote call. Since this is a call to the `NetConnection.call`, I should be able to pass variable arguments but since I'm encapsulating the `NetConnection.call` it's throwing up errors. This is what my method currently looks like:

```
public function call( method : String, callback : Function, ... args ) : void
{
    var responder : Responder;

    responder = new Responder( callback, onResponderStatus );

    this._nc.call( this._remoteObject + "." + method, responder, args );
}
```

As you can see, my method takes a variable arguments parameter as the last parameter. I'm trying to pass these parameters to the `NetConnection.call` method. But, within the scope of my method, `args` would be of type Array. How do I properly forward the variable arguments to `NetConnection.call`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Function::apply`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/Function.html#apply%28%29) is what you are looking for ... in the end, it should look like this:

```
this._nc.call.apply(this._nc, [this._remoteObject + "." + method, responder].concat(args) );
```

greetz

back2dos